# XMLHTTPRequest onreadystatechange readyState is always 1?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

My readyState in my onreadystatechange callback seems to be stuck at 1.

```
  let req
  function reloadData(){
    let now = new Date()
    url = 'liveData?' + now.getTime()
    try {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest()
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        } catch (oc) {
          alert("No AJAX Support")
          return
        }
      }
    }

    req.onreadystatechange = processData
    req.open("GET", url, true)
    req.send(null)
  }
  function processData(){
    alert(req.readyState)
    // If req shows "complete"
    if (req.readyState == 4){
      dataDiv = document.getElementById('currentData')
      // If "OK"
      if (req.status == 200)
      {
        // Set current data text
        dataDiv.innerHTML = req.responseText
      }
      else
      {
        // Flag error
        dataDiv.innerHTML = '<p>There was a problem retrieving data: ' + req.statusText + '</p>'
      }
    }
  }
```

the request itself works and I log when /liveData gets a request and I get that log as well. I have no errors and the alert itself works so it is calling properly, but the readyState is at 1 at all times.

Comment: Just curious -- are you actually supporting Internet Explorer at a version less than 7? That's the only set of browsers that need `ActiveXObject`...

Comment: I didn't know what I was doing because I havent worked with xmlhttprequest before so I took an example (I shoulda read docs but time crunch) and modified it for my needs and everything but the readyState works. However would it make a difference?

Comment: Probably not, I was just curious. It's been a loooong time since I've seen `ActiveXObject` :). `readyState` is something that's controlled by the server; if it's stuck at 1 (open), it means the browser has connected to the server and opened a connection, but the server hasn't responded to the request yet. Not much you can do from the client side except time out and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the server just wasn't sending a response, thank you Heretic Monkey for pointing that out in the comments.